# Are there any documentaries on the subject of Medieval and/or Renaissance western music and its practice?

Tags: history, education, medieval

I am looking mostly for the essential information on polypohony, gregorian chant, techniques of the time and their development etc, in order to get a grasp of the subject, names and times so I can later on focus my study on books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a documentary which is readily available, depending on where in the world you are located, and which appears to have some relevance to what you want:

[BBC Howard Goodall's Story of Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Y6NPahlDE)

If you want to hear some examles, there is a whole playlist of short performances here, which gives you a lot of names, but no discussion:

[History of Western Music](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAvO8mkSoJEHs2uNaOiT5JdIUJKT6Bs7-)

and here:

[A Brief History of the Western Musical Thought](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H25wx8pbTQU)

You might also be interested in some of the (free) courses offered by Coursera. For example:

[Western Music History through Performance](https://www.coursera.org/course/musichistoryperforms)

You might need to register with the site to get access to this, and probably only week one of the course is relevant (A brief history of notation), but I have found the several lectures in week 1 of the course very informative.

I will have to leave it to you to decide if any of these are "good" ...

Comment: Thank you. I have already watched BBC's Story of Music and it is very close to what I have in mind. I am looking for something focusing on the Medieval and Renaissance eras.